# Алгоритм преобразования орграфа в ациклический орграф DAG за счет изменения ориентации обратных ребер

Tags: алгоритм, графы, структуры-данных

лабораторное задание, но я  нигде не могу найти информацию о таком алгоритме.

Comment: Небось не `DAG`, а тривиальное ОАГ? Ну тогда просто спросите у Вики, что такое "Ациклическая ориентация".

Comment: "Любой граф имеет ациклическую ориентацию. Одним из способов создания ациклических ориентаций является упорядочение вершин с последующим ориентированием каждого ребра от более ранней вершины в списке к более поздней" - из вики.  как именно нужно упорядочить вершины? как ориентировать ребра?  объясните пожалуйста  на примере такого графа:  вершины  1,2,3,4.         
 ребра 1-2 2-3 3-1  3-4 4-1

Comment: *вершины 1,2,3,4. ребра 1-2 2-3 3-1 3-4 4-1* Ну русским же по белому пишут: *с последующим ориентированием каждого ребра от более ранней вершины в списке к более поздней*. Если более поздней считать, к примеру, вершину с бОльшим номером, то нужно "перевернуть" те рёбра, где номер вершины начала больше номера вершины конца. Это ребро номер 3 (т.к. 3 больше, чем 1, его конвертируем в 1->3) и ребро номер 5 (т.к. 4 больше, чем 1, его конвертируем в 1->4).